# Touch ID Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

Login credentials of my app will expire in a certain period of time. I'm planning to enable touch ID login for the app as well. My question is how the UI logic should be implemented to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the credential is expired, block UI by showing modal View Controller which will ask user to login using touch ID or in other ways.